# Gettings multiple features at pixel

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2

I got an app to do there is a map and lots of points which represent a pictures, for example i got 3 pictures in 1 coordinate, and other pictures has other identical coordinates. But now i need once i click on point in the map which should open a gallery of pictures taken at that coordinate... But i ran into an issue that only it gets one picture, not 3...

here is my code:

```
var displayFeatureInfo = function (pixel) {
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature) {
    return feature;
});

var info = document.getElementById('info');
if (feature) {
    var thumbUrl = feature.get('url');
    $.ajax({
        url: thumbUrl,
        dataType: 'JSON'
    }).then(function (data) {
        info.innerHTML = "<h3>" + feature.get('caption') + "</h3> " +
        '<br /><img src=' + data.thumbnails[0].small.url + ' />';
    })

} else {
    info.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
}

if (feature !== highlight) {
    if (highlight) {
        featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
    }
    if (feature) {
        featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(feature);
    }
    highlight = feature;
}
```

};

here is the loading of pictures:

```
function loadImages() {
///Below url is from PSN personal onedrive. Exchange with relevant other
///https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/Billeder/2012%20Leshoto:
var sourcePhoto = new ol.source.Vector({});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    // beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);}

}).then(function (data) {
    //we process the data into features we can add to our map
    var items = data.value; //all images in folder
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        //only if geo images
        if (items[i].location != null) {
            var itemUrl = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0" +
                items[i].parentReference.path + "/"
                + items[i].name +
                "?expand=thumbnails,children(expand=thumbnails(select=large,c200x150_Crop))&access_token=" +
                token;//.thumbnails[0].large.url, // url to the full image
            var pos = new ol.geom.Point(new ol.proj.transform([items[i].location.longitude, items[i].location.latitude], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"));
            var feat = new ol.Feature({                    
                geometry: pos, //the geomtry that maps the image on ground
                url: itemUrl,
                caption: '', //Image title
                thumbnail: '' //a thumbnail represenation of the image
            });
            sourcePhoto.addFeature(feat);
        }
    }
    layPhoto.setSource(sourcePhoto);
    map.addLayer(layPhoto);
})
```

}

So `forEachFeatureAtPixel` only returns one feature of only one picture, but not for all pictures. So my main question is when i `addFeature` on `loadImages` function should I somehow assign it like an array of photos to that coordinate and not as entity ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions to fix this issue and may be more :

1) When user clicks on a point int the map, get the coordinates of clicked point and then compare it with all coordinates of other features of this layer, and add the same coordinates features into an array while looping.

2) Use Strategy of **clusters** as in below link, where the layer will combine all features near each other with specific distance (you specify), if you want all features with same coordinates you can specify 0 distance, in **featureclick** you will get an array of features grouped on the clicked feature :

**Code:**

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: features
});

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 0,
  source: source
});
```

**Source:**
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/cluster.html?mode=raw